# Filteringtable and lazy loading from REST

Tags: vaadin

I have Filtertable add-on integrated with local-data processing (including filter bar). Now I need to fetch data from REST web service. Which container is the best for this case? SQL container needs SQL Queries. Should I take some base container and override appropriate methods?

**EDIT:** Solved by using LazyQueryContainer

Answer (score 1):

This largely depends an what REST service you use, and what type of updates you wish to do.

The most consistent aproach would be to use a REST Container,
but as far as I know no one has implemented this yet.

What you find is a JSON container, which can use JSON "sources" as containers.

https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/jsoncontainer

Answer (score 0):

If you can migrate to Vaadin 8 you can take a look at the https://github.com/mvysny/vaadin8-restdataprovider-example to fetch data from REST including paging, sorting and filtering, along with auto-generated filter bar.

[image: Screenshot of the vaadin8-restdataprovider app]

Comment: Very nice! Do you have some screenshot?

Comment: @Mejmo Yup, added :)